# A Div section not executing

Tags: php, html

In my below given code, the second DIV section is not executing. The PHP code contained therein is not executing. I added a test echo, but it is not displaying it also. Why the control is not reaching there.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Add/Update Election Category</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Lib/entryformstyle.css" type="text/css"/>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="sectionEntryForm" class="entryForm" style="width:300px">   <!-- Begin of Entry Form Section -->
            <form action="electioncategorymaster.php" method="post" id="frmElectionCategoryMaster" name="frmElectionCategoryMaster">
                <table id="tblEntryForm" cols="3" class="entryFormTable">
                    <tr bgcolor="white">
                        <td colspan="3" align="center">Add / Update Election Category</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Election category name:</td>
                        <td colspan="2"><input id="inElectionCategoryName" name="inElectionCategoryName" accept="text/plain" maxlength="80" class="entryFormInputBoxColorCompulsoryField" size="40"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Total members:</td>
                        <td colspan="2"><input id="inTotalMembers" name="inTotalMembers" accept="text/plain" maxlength="6" class="entryFormInputBoxColor" size="40"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Short description:</td>
                        <td colspan="2"><textarea id="inShortDesc" name="inShortDesc" class="entryFormInputBoxColor" cols="31"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>                   
                    <tr>
                        <td>Chairman:</td>
                        <td colspan="2"><input id="inChairman" name="inChairman" accept="text/plain" maxlength="80" class="entryFormInputBoxColor" size="40"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center"><input id="btnMenu" name="btnMenu" type="button" value="Return to Menu"></td>
                        <td align="center"><input id="btnClear" name="btnClear" type="button" value="Clear Entries"></td>
                        <td align="center"><input id="btnUpdate" name="btnUpdate" type="submit" value="Update Record"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>  <!-- End of Entry Form Section -->

        <br>

        <div id="sectionGrid">  <!-- Begin of Grid Section -->
            <table id="tblGrid">
                <tr>
                    <?php
                        echo "---"; 
                        require("../Lib/displaygrid.php");
                        displaygrid::SetGridWithValues("ecid As ID, ecname As Category","electioncategorymaster");
                     ?>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>  <!-- End of Grid Section -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. What is the extension of the file
   you're talking about? Does it have
   .php extension?
2. If it has .php extension, make sure
   it resides on a web-server
   (somewhere in /httpdocs, /www of
   similar folder)
3. If file extension is .html, then you should rename it to .php or add `AddHandler x-httpd-php html` definition to httpd.conf or .htaccess file.
4. How do you open this file? You
   cannot just open it with the default
   application that OS suggests. It
   should be opened from the browser:
   http://localhost/site/file.php
5. Make sure apache have mod_php
   installed. Check whether there is
   string containing 'LoadModule
   php5_module' in httpd.conf
6. You could also insert code to the
   beginning of the file to be sure you
   get all errors:

   ```
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
   ```

Comment: Good overview and checklist! +1

Comment: @altern: Oh yeah... the extension is .html. So how to make a call to another .php file from within the second DIV?